# what does jdbc:hsqldb:hsqlTempFiles mean

Tags: java, hsqldb

In [SimpleORM](http://www.simpleorm.org/sorm/whitepaper.html) (a JAVA ORM library) examples, I see a code like:

```
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsqlTempFiles;shutdown=true;", "sa", "")
```

I am not able to understand the meaning of `hsqlTempFiles` in above. My basic understanding of hsqldb consists of file/mem/res/hsql based access modes. In SimpleORM code archive, I do see a file named  hsqlTempFiles.properties and hsqlTempFiles.script.

Is this an older way to refer to file based hsqldb databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after `hsqldb:` [is the name of the database to connect to](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#running_inprocess-sect). Specifying the name of the file without `file:` may just be legacy or backward-compatible logic.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to confirm. simpleorm is shipped with hsqldb-1_8_0_10.jar

Comment: This is the full form for both 1.8.x and 2.x "jdbc:hsqldb:file:hsqlTempFiles;shutdown=true;" For backward compatibility, it still works without file: